# how to use kubectl annotate in pulumi?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, pulumi, infrastructure-as-code

I am working in a Cloud Solution with Google Cloud as a provider. I want to deploy it using IaC tool (Pulumi). I want to execute the below command in a declarative style:

```yaml
kubectl annotate serviceaccount ksaName -n cluster-namespace \
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account=fully-quallified-service-account-name
```

I am currently using this workaround (proposed by @lblackstone):

```js
import { local } from "@pulumi/command";

// We could also use `RemoteCommand` to run this from within a node in the cluster
new local.Command(“annotate”, {
    create: "kubectl annotate serviceaccount ksaName -n cluster-namespace \
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account=fully-quallified-service-account-name",
    environment: {
        KUBECONFIG: <kubeconfig>,
    },
});
```

Just in case (I tried this and it did not work also). I am attempting Workload Identity to work:

```js
const ksa = new k8s.core.v1.ServiceAccount(
  ksaName,
  {
    metadata: {
      name: ksaName,
      namespace: namespaceName,
      annotations: {
        "iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account": gsa.name,
      },
    },
  },
  { provider: clusterProvider, dependsOn: [gsa] }
);

...

/ Create a Kubernetes provider instance that uses our cluster from above.
export const clusterProvider = new k8s.Provider(inputName, {
  kubeconfig: kubeconfig,
  enableServerSideApply: true,
});
```

And I am aware of [this feature was shipped](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-kubernetes/issues/264) in order to address a similar issue. The problem resides in, I do not really know how to use it to fit my case. [It seems to work with patch](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/kubernetes/how-to-guides/managing-resources-with-server-side-apply/).